# Как можно на этапе компиляции проверить, имеет ли строка слово `std`

Tags: c++, stl

столкнулся с проблемой:

```
template<typename T, int size>
void input()
{
    if  constexpr (string(typeid(T).name()).find("std")) // проверить если это STL-структура данных/ тут ошибка
    {
            T t(size);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            {
                typename T::value_type temp;
                cin >> temp;
                t.push_back(temp);
            }
            return t;
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку: `выражение не вычисляется как константа`. Как можно на этапе компиляции проверить, имеет ли строка слово `std`.

Comment: Это так на контейнеры хотите проверять? А если пользовательский контейнер? В любом случае, использовать для этого typeid - не самая хорошая идея. Его результат не стандартизирован

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для проверки типа на то, является ли он контейнером, как раз есть библиотека концептов https://github.com/MiSo1289/more_concepts. Можно как просто подключить её, так и скопировать код нужных концептов оттуда. В будущих стандартах языка их могут добавить в стандартную библиотеку.

Вам нужен `more_concepts::container<T>`, судя по всему.

```
/// From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container:
/// "A Container is an object used to store other objects and taking care
/// of the management of the memory used by the objects it contains."
///
/// Satisfied by all well-behaved standard containers.
/// Is not satisfied by vector<bool>.
template <typename C>
concept container =
requires(C& cont, C const& const_cont)
{
    typename C::value_type;
    requires decayed<typename C::value_type>;

    typename C::reference;
    typename C::const_reference;
    // Well-behaved containers should not rely on proxies for iterators / references.
    requires std::same_as<typename C::reference, typename C::value_type&>;
    requires std::same_as<typename C::const_reference, typename C::value_type const&>;

    typename C::iterator;
    typename C::const_iterator;
    requires std::forward_iterator<typename C::iterator>;
    requires std::forward_iterator<typename C::const_iterator>;
    requires std::convertible_to<typename C::iterator, typename C::const_iterator>;
    requires std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<typename C::iterator>, typename C::value_type>;
    requires std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<typename C::const_iterator>, typename C::value_type>;
    requires std::same_as<std::iter_reference_t<typename C::iterator>, typename C::reference> or
             std::same_as<std::iter_reference_t<typename C::iterator>, typename C::const_reference>;
    requires std::same_as<std::iter_reference_t<typename C::const_iterator>, typename C::const_reference>;

    typename C::difference_type;
    typename C::size_type;
    requires std::signed_integral<typename C::difference_type>;
    requires std::unsigned_integral<typename C::size_type>;
    // size_type should be able to represent all positive values of difference_type.
    requires std::in_range<typename C::size_type>(
        std::numeric_limits<typename C::difference_type>::max());
    // difference_type should be the same as the one defined by iterator_traits.
    requires std::same_as<
        typename C::difference_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<typename C::iterator>::difference_type>;
    requires std::same_as<
        typename C::difference_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<typename C::const_iterator>::difference_type>;

    // Containers of equality comparable values should be equality comparable
    requires not std::equality_comparable<typename C::value_type> or
             std::equality_comparable<C>;

    // Containers should satisfy at least the strongest object concept satisfied by value_type.
    requires not std::movable<typename C::value_type> or
             std::movable<C>;
    requires not std::copyable<typename C::value_type> or
             std::copyable<C>;
    requires not std::semiregular<typename C::value_type> or
             std::semiregular<C>;
    requires not std::regular<typename C::value_type> or
             std::regular<C>;

    // Iterators
    { cont.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::iterator>;
    { cont.end() } -> std::same_as<typename C::iterator>;
    { const_cont.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { const_cont.end() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { cont.cbegin() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;
    { cont.cend() } -> std::same_as<typename C::const_iterator>;

    // Capacity
    { const_cont.max_size() } -> std::same_as<typename C::size_type>;
    { const_cont.empty() } -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};
```

Comment: Замечу, что с точки зрения этого концепта, `std::string` - контейнер, а `int[3]` - нет. Хотя с точки зрения практического применения (например, ввода из стандартного потока) должно быть наоборот.